# Authenticating to Web Service VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, authentication

Hi I am trying to Authenticate to my web service and missing something..

My Service reference is called - MBSDKServiceLD 
My Web Reference is called - LANDeskMBSDK

I have these connected in Visual Studio 2013 And are resolving methods in the code

Here is my code for the authentication but its not complete..

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Net

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objExec As Object
Dim objNetwork As Object
Dim strComputer As String
Dim strUser As String
Dim User As String
Dim Password As String
Dim Domain As String
Dim URL As String
Dim Cred As String

Dim strTaskName As String
Dim strPackageName As String
Dim strDeliveryMethod As String
Dim strCustomGroup As String

Dim boolStartNow As Boolean
Dim WakeUpMachines As Boolean
Dim boolCommonTask As Boolean

Dim strAutoSync As String
Dim TaskID As String

Dim strConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim LDWebService
Dim intTaskID As String
Dim LDService As Object

Dim strDeviceName As String

Sub RunLANDeskTask(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal LDService As MBSDKServiceLD.MBSDKSoap)



End Sub

Sub CreateTask

    User = "username1"
    Password = "password1"
    Domain = "domain1"

    URL = "http://myserver/MBSDKService/MsgSDK.asmx?WSDL"
    Dim MyCredentails As New System.Net.CredentialCache()
    Dim NetCred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(User, Password, Domain)
    MyCredentails.Add(New Uri(URL), "Basic", NetCred)

strPackageName = "Adobe Acrobat XI PRO"
    strDeliveryMethod = "Standard push distribution"

    Dim strTargetDevice As String
    strTargetDevice = Nothing

    strTaskName = strPackageName & " - " & DateTime.Now & " -Provisioning Task for" & "   " & strComputer

    Try
        RunLANDeskTask(LANDeskMBSDK, LDService.CreateTask(strTaskName,   strDeliveryMethod, strPackageName, False, False, strAutoSync).TaskID)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error creating task")

    End Try
End Sub
```

What comes after this part or have i got this totally wrong?

When I type LDService. I see all the methods so I am connecting to the reference in VS but not authenticating.

Comment: First things first: are you sure the url is valid?

Comment: edited now.. but yes that is the correct URL - i have this working in powershell but i need it in VB.net.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted all the code that is calling the service. But from what you posted so far, you need to initialise the generated proxy class and pass your credentials to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got this working... But i have to run the code under an account that can access the Web service -

```
    Dim URL As String = "http://server/MBSDKService/MsgSDK.asmx?WSDL"
    Dim myService As New LANDeskMBDSK.MBSDK
    myService.Url = URL

    Dim CredCache As New System.Net.CredentialCache
    CredCache.Add(New Uri(myService.Url), "Basic", Cred)

    myService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

Answer (score 0):

It should really be as simple as this (sorry it's in c#):

```
MyWebService svc = new MyWebService();            
svc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserID, pwd);
bool result = svc.MyWebMethod();
```

The following might be helpful:

[This is quite old, but the comments are good.](http://intellitect.com/calling-web-services-using-basic-authentication/)

I've just found the following on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996415.aspx), which looks like what you want:

```
localhost.Sample svc = new localhost.Sample();
try {
CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
NetworkCredential netCred = 
    new NetworkCredential( "Example", "Test$123", "sseely2" );
credCache.Add( new Uri(svc.Url), "Basic", netCred );
svc.Credentials = credCache;
```

Comment: Thanks.. can you tell me if My Service reference is called - MBSDKServiceLD My Web Reference is called - LANDeskMBSDK. How i would add those to that example?  i obv need to replace the localhost.sample but what with?

Comment: if your service is called LANDeskMBSDK, the proxy class may have the same name. So try to substitute localhost.Sample with LANDeskMBSDK.

Comment: Hi That doesn't work.. I need to instantiate the Proxy and i canot see how